# What is writer.getverticalposition replacement in itext 7

Tags: java, itext

I was using writer.getverticalposition in previous version of itext
so i can find out the remaining space
but it is not in itext 7.1.3
So how can i find out the remaining space of the pdf page using itext 7.1.3

Comment: You also asked this question on the iText Jira and one of our developers has already answered your question there. You are welcome to copy the answer to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using this code you can find the rest of the page size of your document

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello");
doc.add(p);

LayoutArea currentArea = doc.getRenderer().getCurrentArea();
Rectangle rectangle = currentArea.getBBox();
System.out.println(rectangle.getHeight());
```

The rectangle getHeight gives the height of the rest of the area left in the pdf page,

Like that the rectangle has information's like X,Y positions etc.